# Scan Hbase where column between two values

Tags: java, load, hbase

I'm fairly new to Hbase and currently working on a Java 11 application loading data from an Hbase 2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315
The table I'm loading has a numeric value as a rowKey and a column "createdAt" which holds a string with a timestamp.

For all I care, the table looks like this:

| rowKey | createdAt | name |
| --- | --- | --- |

I inherited the snipped from one of the previous developers, loading data like that, but in their case, the rowKey was identical to the createdAt column, in my case it's not.
They used

```
config.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START, rowKeyFrom);
config.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP, rowKeyTo);
```

where `config` ist the `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`, from the hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315 which works fine.

As far as I understand, what they did is "Load data where **rowKey** is between than `rowKeyFrom` and `rowKeyTo` but I want "Load data where **createdAt** is between `rowKeyFrom`and `rowKeyTo`.

I don't know how to do that and I cannot change the hbase tables or dependencies in any way (company rules).

Update:
Basically the problem is "How do I use another column as rowKey without having to scan everything?"

Comment: There is a huge difference between the original query and the one that you want. The original only scans the rows in range, while your query will scan the entire table.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I'll update the question to make this clearer

Comment: `How do I use another column as rowKey without having to scan everything?` - in HBase, you can't

Comment: In that case, this is the answer i needed.

Comment: @shay__ If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it